# How to add dynamic view inside a recycler view row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have one recycler view and inside each row I have one linear layout in which I have to insert some views dynamically according to data on each row.

I have tried

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
>     View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sales_total_item_with_img,null);
>     holder.dynamicLinearLayout.addView(view);
> }
> ```
>
> the above code is written inside onBindHolder method and working but it is inflating each time I scroll and this thing is just adding more and more views

Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong and suggest me the better approach?

Comment: You should check the existing scenario before adding views dynamically, like you have to compare the amount of dynamically added views to the amount of data in each and every model object of your list. if your dynamically added views differs in number or it is 0 remove all the views and add from scratch for that particular object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try holder.dynamicLinearLayout.removeAllViews() before for loop

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late reply but still just want to share code for Kotlin. In BindViewHolder just do like this.

```
 holder.llDescription.removeAllViews()
    for (i in 0 until  data.description.size) {
        val childView: View = context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_description, null)
        val tvDescription : TextView = childView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription)
        tvDescription.text = data.description[i].title
        holder.llDescription.addView(childView)
    }
```